# My question was edited and now it looks like that the answer is in the question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

I posted this question a few weeks ago:

[Do monks have a gempukku ceremony?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135180/do-monks-have-a-gempukku-ceremony)

As you can see, the second quote in this question seems to answer the question. If you look at the edit history, you can see that I didn't actually posted this quote, it was added during an edit.

This quote is very relevant to this question of course, but I thought it would be better to put it in an answer, because as it is, it looks like my question makes no sense.

Should I revert this edit?

Answer (score 9):

Feel free to undo the edit if you feel that it changes your question too much.

I wouldn't say that it make it looks like your question makes no sense, but it adds to the confusion: the first quote says that the monks of Dragon Clan have no gempukku, the second that they do not bother with it, which is different.

But that's your question, if you don't like the edit, feel free to revert it.

You can do that by clicking on the last 'Edited [Date]' mention under your post, then click on the rollback link on the various edits to your question. For a question that has been edited several times, you can choose which version you want to go back to, which also gives you the possibility to rollback everything and go back to the original post of the question.

[image: Edited Link]
[image: Rollback]

Comment: @nitsua60 #nopressure... :p

Comment: Looks great! (#pressure...nomanaskfor)